# Salesforce CPQ - Amend Contract

Tags: cpq

I need to amend the contract in the Salesforce CPQ from a third party tool.
As from the documentation there is a way to do it - 
https://community.steelbrick.com/t5/Developer-Guidebook/Public-API-Overview/ta-p/5689

Though i have tried to do it using the swagger(as mentioned in the doc). Iam not able to do it. Can someone provide an example to do so.

regards,
Srikanth.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use the ContractAmender API provided by Salesforce to answer your needs :
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.cpq_dev_api.meta/cpq_dev_api/cpq_api_contract_amender.htm

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).